# A.e. equal functions for semifinite measure

Tags: measure-theory

As a homework in our Measure + Integration Theory course we had the following statement:
If $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f, g: X \to [0, \infty)$ are measurable functions s.t. $\int_E fd\mu = \int_E gd\mu$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$, then $f=g$ a.e.
We also had to give a counterexample to this statement if the measure is not $\sigma$-finite.

**Question:** I am now wondering: Does the above statement still hold if the measure is semi-finite? If yes: What would be a way to prove this? If no: Counterexample?

Intuitively I would say that the statement still holds. The statement holds for the semifinite measure spaces I can think of (which are basically just the counting measure on non-countable sets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you prove the $\sigma$ finite case? Because basically the same proof works here:

If $f =g$ a.e. does **not** hold, there is some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that the set

$$
F = \{x \mid f(x), g(x) \leq n \text{ and } f(x) \geq g(x) + 1/n \}
$$

has positive (or infinite) measure. (**Why?**) Of course, one might have to change the roles of $f,g$ for this.

By semi finiteness, there is some $E \subset F$ of finite, positive measure. This yields

$$
\int_E g d\mu =\int_E f d\mu \geq \int_E (g + 1/n) d\mu = \int_E g d \mu + \frac{\mu(E)}{n},
$$

which yields $\mu(E)=0$, a contradiction.

This last step uses the fact that $\int_E g d\mu$ is finite. You should convince yourself that this is the case (why?).

Comment: Thank you. The proof I gave for the $\sigma$-finite case was based on the same statement for integrable functions (which we had in the lectures).  
For the two Why-points (just to be sure):  
1) Since $\mu (\{ f, g \leq n\}) \to \mu(X)$ and $\mu(\{f > g \}) > 0$ by assumption. Just pick $n$ large enough  
2) $\int_E gd\mu \leq n \mu (E) <\infty$

Comment: 2) Yes. 1) Here I would simply argue that a countable union of null-sets is null, but the union is $\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}$, which is not null by assumption. The fact that $\mu(E_n) \to \mu(X)$ alone does not help you much, in particular if $\mu(X) = \infty$.